# Listbox No Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been up and down looking on the internet and many people seem to have this problem but its generally solved by changing the container to a grid, constraining the height etc. etc. I can't to seem to get this to work.
I have an observableCollection thats feeding into a DataTemplate. I can't for th life of me get the scrollbar working. Its there but not enabling. Thanks Scott

```
<TabItem Header="select a call" x:Name="TabActiveCalls" Style="{DynamicResource MyTabItem}" FontFamily="QuickType">
            <Grid Margin="0.125,0.412,3.125,0" Height="471" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="839.14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="741.14">
                        <StackPanel Height="28" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="733.14" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtHistoryFound" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="*" Foreground="#FFE20A0A" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="filter by:" Margin="5,0,10,0" Foreground="#FF585AD4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="call no" Margin="5,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF5E88DA"/>
                            <TextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" x:Name="searchCallNo" TextChanged="searchCallNo_TextChanged"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="67" Foreground="#FF1341B1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,10,0" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="postcode" Margin="5,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF5E88DA"/>
                            <TextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" x:Name="searchPostcode" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="67" Foreground="#FF1341B1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,10,0" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Height="23" x:Name="txtSiteName" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF0E7C0B" Width="409" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="Airedale International Ltd" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Width="733.14" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Border Height="21" Margin="5,6,8,0" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFC0BABA">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFD0D5DE">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CALL NO. / DATE DUE/ CUSTOMER" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource ListTitle}" FontSize="10.667" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ENGINEER / ADDRESS" Margin="114,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource ListTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="REPORT" Margin="43,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource ListTitle}" RenderTransformOrigin="2.543,0.429" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CALL" Margin="28,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource ListTitle}" RenderTransformOrigin="2.543,0.429" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="POSITION" Margin="43,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource ListTitle}" RenderTransformOrigin="2.543,0.429" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Image Height="56" Width="90" Source="/ComfortReportEng;component/Media/Images/comfort_group.png"/>
                </StackPanel>
                    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateReportList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsReportList}}" 
                    Margin="5,56,8,0" MaxHeight="415" Height="415" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

many thanks for getting back. Here is my DataTempate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateReportList">
        <Border Margin="0,2,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFA19C9C" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" Width="810.52" Height="50" >
            <Grid Background="#FF737B89" Height="48" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="274" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <StackPanel Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CallNo, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FF7DF51E" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DateDue, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=d}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FFFFEA00" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="456" Orientation="Vertical" Height="46" Margin="274,1,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding EngineerName, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FFCAE5C6" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="140"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ReportStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FF7DF51E" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="50"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CallStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FF7DF51E" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="50"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="50"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="#FFFFEA00" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="483.12"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid Width="56" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12.52,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Name="imgInfo" Source="/ComfortReportEng;component/Media/Images/Info4.png" Margin="24,8,0,0" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgInfo_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Must be a bug. I have the following only..

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="ComfortReportEng.Views.EngineerReport.EngineerReport"
Title="Engineer Report" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsReportList"/>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0.125,0.412,3.125,0" Height="471">
        <ListBox Margin="23,64,3,0" Width="834.14"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsReportList}}" 
            x:Name="lbReportList" SelectionChanged="lbReportList_SelectionChanged" Background="#FFEEEFE4" />
    </Grid>
```

and code is

```
 private void LoadReportList()
    {
        int number = 0;
        List<int> myNumbers = new List<int>();
        while (number < 80)
        {
            myNumbers.Add(number);
            number += 1;
        }
        _cvsReportList = (CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("cvsReportList"));
        _cvsReportList.Source = myNumbers;
    }
```

This was copied over from another project. Completely confused. Please don't worry. It's not a logical problem. Please take this as a close call with no solution. Cheers again Scott

Just to give this completeness. I am not sure why this happens but here is it.

```
if (System.Environment.MachineName == "SCOTT-PC")
        {
            this.txtUserName.Text = "Scott Fisher";
            this.txtPassword.Password = "palace";
            //LoginOK();

        }
        else
            Keyboard.Focus(this.txtUserName);
```

If I clear the comments on LoginOK procedure I will get no scrollbar. With it commented and I interact with the login screen then everything is fine. Finally here is the code for the LoginOK.
    if (LoginService.CheckLogin(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password.ToString()))
                {
                    Helpers.User.ThisUser = this.txtUserName.Text;

```
                EngineerReport.EngineerReport engReport = new EngineerReport.EngineerReport()
                {
                    Owner = Window.GetWindow(this),
                    WindowStartupLocation =
                        System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.
                        CenterOwner
                };
                this.Hide();
                engReport.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                this.txtPassword.Password = "";
                this.txtPassword.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: Can you just wrap what you want to have a scroll bar within a ScrollViewer?

Comment: Sorry. didn't work. I tried that earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide you DataTemplate as I believe I have just managed to mock up what you are trying to achieve and I have scrollbars visible and working form the start.

Here is the xaml that I used for the DataTemplate for the ListBox:

```
    <ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource MusicData}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Album}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock>No.</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=No}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Title</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Title}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Hope this helps.

I also found a piece of code I used a while back and this might help. You can try setting the ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

This will work with any items control as stated in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx

One final thing I can suggest is to create your own ControlTemplate for the ListBox Like so:

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

Comment: Hi. I have added my dataTemplate. Thanks again

Comment: Strange as I have managed to get your data template working with my text box and the only thing I am doing differently is my DataTemplate is with in the ListBox itself instead of being a separate resource e.g: <ListBox><ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate> 'template here' </DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox> can't understand why this would be what is causing mine to work and yours not but have you given it ago. Also I don't specify "ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" as they are auto by default.

Comment: I know. I will run through the posts and try again, maybe even moving the template. I can't understand either. Could it be the way the class forms the data?

Comment: Never had this happen to my I have also edited my orriginal answer with something else you could try.

Comment: Nope. It must be something to do with the data. I have moved as stated but no joy. Also I dont seem to be able to add the ItemsPanel. Errors the XAML. Banging my head now! Thanks again

Comment: I can scroll up and down with the mouse wheel. Actually both vertical and horizontal are not enabled

Comment: So they are not enabled even when you change them to be set as always visible instead of auto.

Comment: I found the problem. I have a login screen first of all. I automated the process so while I was developing i didn't need to enter my details each time. Bypassing that clears the error. So it's a bug in there thats having a random knock on effect. I will report back once I have isolated it. All very strange!! Scott

Comment: Just to give this completeness. I am not sure why this happens but here is it. Above with code.